# Submit Form Onchange Checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

This is my PHP code:
I have to make when I check or uncheck a checkbox, then immediately update a value into the database.
I need to do this with PHP or Javascript.

```
<?php
session_start();
include("head.php"); 
include("dbconnection.php");  // database connectie

if (isset($_SESSION['login']))
{
   echo "<h1>Contacten</h1>";
   echo "<h3>Welkom ".$_SESSION['login']."</h3><br/>";
   include("menu.php");
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM `customers` ORDER BY Created DESC ";  // selecteer uit tabel customers
   echo "<table class='overzicht'>
           <tr style='background-color: lightgray; min-height: 200px;' >
               <td colspan='9'>
                    <a href='#' id='module-tab-1' class='toggle' data-prod-cus='1'>
                       <h1 style='margin-bottom: 0px;'>Alle Contacten</h1>
                       <div class='left-image hi'></div>
                     </a>
               </td>
           </tr>
           <tr style='background-color: orange; display:none;' class='cus1' >
            <th>Allemaal</th>
            <th>Datum</th>
            <th>Naam</th>
            <th>Bedrijf</th>
            <th>Email:</th>
            <th>SMS</th>
            <th>Storing</th>
        </tr>";
foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
    echo "
        <tr class='cus1' style='display:none'>";
        if ($row['All'] == 1)
            {
                echo "<td>
                    <input type='checkbox' name='all' checked>
                </td>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<td>
                    <input type='checkbox' name='all'>
                </td>";
            }
            echo "
            <td>
                ".$row['Created']."  
            </td>
            <td>
                ".$row['Name']." 
            </td>
            <td>
                ".$row['Company']."
            </td>
            <td>
                ".$row['Email']."
            </td>
            <td>
                ".$row['SMS']."
            </td>
            <td>
                ".$row['StoringsID']."
            </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo '</table>';
}
else
{
   header("location:index.php");  // ga terug naar het inlogscherm
}
include("Javascripts.php");
```

Can someone tell me how to do this?
I don't know how to do this.
I saw some examples, but they didn't work out for me.
I used Jquery but I don't know how to update the database then.

Comment: You should use Ajax with PHP to perform the task!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be a simple form that is submitted on change:
(Replace thispageurl.php with your url)

```
<form action="thispageurl.php" method="post">
  <input id="yourinputid" name="input">
 </form>
```

Now you can add the following js,
It submits the form on change:

```
window.onload=function(){
 console.log("load..."); changer=document.getElementById("yourinputid");
console.log(changer);
changer.onchange=function(){
  console.log("changed");
  //you could also use komals code here ( it does not reload the page)
  changer.parentNode.submit();
 };
 };
```

Now you need the php (in thispageurl.php or save.php if you use komals code) to catch this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["input"])){
 $newvalue=$_POST["input"];
//update your mysql
}
?>
```

A small note:
Instead of echoing you can simply write the html into the php. Thats easier to read:

```
<?php if($value==true){ ?>
Value is true
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Could u put this into a jsfiddle? It doesn't work for me!

Comment: you cant put php into a fiddle... doesnt work doesnt mean that you have to downvote directly

Comment: May look into the console, analyze what may not work, i cant help you with that until ive got a specific error...

Comment: Could you try the change? Ive added a few logs to detect the mistake

Answer (score 1):

You can save data by using ajax request

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'save.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'id='+23,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
      $("#message-box").text("Successfully!");
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      var errResponse = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
    },
  });
```

Get checkbox event

```
<input type='checkbox' name='all' class="mycheckbox" checked>

if($('.mycheckbox').prop('checked')) {
  // do something when checked
} else {
  // do something else when not
}
```